# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis but I have matching pairs

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I'm getting the missing right parenthesis error on this query. What am I missing here, I see 5 left and 5 right parenthesis.  What I'm trying to do is to only return rows with the most current date.

```
WITH snCTE AS 
(
   SELECT
    T1.column1
    ,T1.column2
    ,T2.column3
    ,T2.column4
    ,T1.datefield
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY datefield DESC) AS RN
    FROM dBtable1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dBtable2 T2 ON (T1.columnid=T2.columnid AND T1.otherfield=T2.otherfield)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbtable3 AS T3 WHERE T3.column1 = T1.column1)
)

SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, datefield
FROM snCTE
WHERE snCTE.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is misleading; the real issue is that Oracle does not support `AS` in table aliasing, but only for columns, so

```
FROM dbtable3 AS T3
```

should be edited into

```
FROM dbtable3 T3
```

For example:

```
SQL> select 1 as ONE from dual;

       ONE
----------
         1

SQL> select 1 as ONE from dual D;

       ONE
----------
         1

SQL> select 1 as ONE from dual as D;
select 1 as ONE from dual as D
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error `ORA-00907` is using `AS` in `FROM dbtable3 AS T3`, 
since,  when aliasing *tables* or *subqueries* using `AS` is not allowed in Oracle DB.

So, Just remove that `AS` keyword .

Comment: oh boy, that was in fact misleading. I've removed the "as" and the error is gone, thanks so much! Now I'm facing column ambiguously defined, but I should be able to figure that one out. Thanks!